# Check if all the users in an array have at least one element with an ID equal to an array of IDs?

Tags: javascript

The title is very hard to read, I get it.

I have an array of objects with my users inside of it.

```
const users = [{
  id: 0,
  name: "Test user 01",
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: "Test user 02"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "Test user 03"
}]

const idsToCheck = [2, 4];
```

I want a boolean True if at least one element of users have an ID equal to 2 OR to 4.

I wanted to use **Array.some** but, with an array to check and not a single value, I cannot loop inside of the method without a lint error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some does work.

We are testing numeric IDs against an array of ints - there is reference equality between the IDs and the array elements so the includes is the shortest method over a double some

```js
const users = [{
  id: 0,
  name: "Test user 01",
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: "Test user 02"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "Test user 03"
}]

const idsToCheck = [2, 4];

const bool = users.some(({id}) => idsToCheck.includes(id))
console.log(bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this looks OK to you?

```js
const users = [{
  id: 0,
  name: "Test user 01",
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: "Test user 02"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "Test user 03"
}]

const idsToCheck = [2, 4];

const isPresent = users.some(user => idsToCheck.some(id => id === user.id));

console.log(isPresent)
```

Comment: Why the double some?

Comment: IdsToChek is array, right? Thus we need to check id in the array?

Comment: Cause you used `includes`. The same as `some` but works only with literals or reference equality.

Comment: What would break mine over yours?

Comment: It is not a competition. You claim `includes is the same as some but works only with literals or reference equality`  - so I ask a simple question: _"can you explain where my example would fail since it works with OPs data"_ It is a question, not a criticism.

Comment: It's not to me, it's to the documentation. I believe MDN might help